# How can I set a variable range to a table in excel VBA 2007?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am exporting a data set weekly that needs to be set as a table, however there will be a varying number of rows each week (columns will not change).

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub Eformat_as_table()

    Dim project_count As Integer
    Dim new_table As Range

    project_count = 0
    For a = 1 To 10000
        If Cells(a, 1) = "" Then
        Else
            project_count = project_count + 1
        End If

    Next a

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("format sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(project_count, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Name = "Table"

    Set new_table = Range("Table")

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(new_table), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium1"
End Sub
```

I believe my problem is setting the new table object to the new_table range.

I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just:

```
Sub Eformat_as_table()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("format sheet")
        .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=.Cells(1).CurrentRegion, _
            XlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, TableStyleName:="TableStyleMedium1").Name = "Table2"
    End With
End Sub
```